# Docker: Unable to request another container using requests library

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, python-requests

I am new to docker. I am learning by making microservices.
I have made 2 services . One is express(service1) app which sends dummy json data. Another service is Flask app(service2) which requests express app and sends the same data.

service2

```
import json, requests
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def prices():
    data = requests.get('http://service1:3000/').json()
    return jsonify(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

service1 port 3000:3000
service2 port 5000:5000

When I run docker-compose requests library throws an error

```
service2_   | [2020-10-07 07:41:37,596] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
service2_   | Traceback (most recent call last):
service2_   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
service2_   |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
service2_   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
service2_   |     return self.finalize_request(rv)
service2_   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
service2_   |     response = self.make_response(rv)
service2_   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1740, in make_response
service2_   |     rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
service2_   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_response.py", line 269, in force_type
service2_   |     response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
service2_   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_response.py", line 26, in _run_wsgi_app
service2_   |     return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
service2_   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 1096, in run_wsgi_app
service2_   |     app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
service2_   | TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
service2_   | 172.18.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2020 07:41:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What happens when you do this instead `return jsonify({'result': data})` ?

Comment: What about removing .json()?

Comment: Thanks @matq007 . It works .